# Ошибка в сортировке двумерного массива

Tags: c, сортировка

```
void main(void)
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    int A[N][M], circles = N + M, swap;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = 3 + rand() % 100;
        }
    }


    while (circles)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (circles - 1); i++)
        {
            if (*(A + i) > *(A+i+1)) /*ругается на этот if*/ {
                swap = *(A + i);
                *(A + i) = *(A + i + 1);
                *(A + i + 1) = swap;
            }
        }
        circles--;
    }


}
```

Пишет ошибку:

> Error 3   error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: на  какую конкретно строчку ругается?

Comment: на две строчки после swap = *(A+i);

Comment: http://codepad.org/d56Icpcy

Comment: А всё-таки си или си++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сравнивать строки матрицы и менять их между собой, однако оператора сравнения строк матрицы и оператора присваивания int[] к int[] у вас не существует. На то и ругается.

Answer (score -1):

на две строчки после swap = *(A+i);

```
            *(A + i) = *(A + i + 1);
            *(A + i + 1) = swap;
```

Что здесь получается? Упрощённо?

```
int = int
int = int
```

А что надо?

```
&int = int
&int = int
```

Слева должна быть ссылка, а не абсолютное значение.

Кроме того, на вскидку размер массива странно рассчитывается - `N+M`, вместо `N*M`.

Comment: А оператор разыменовывания как раз ссылку и возвращает. В противном случае действия наподобие `*ptr = value` были бы невозможны.

Comment: @Arhad что ж вы такое-то несёте. Разыменовывание-то здесь и лишнее. По-определению, это получение значения, а не ссылки.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов, всё он правильно сказал.

Comment: `Разыменовывание-то здесь и лишнее` – не лишнее. Обращение к имени массива (не к его элементу через `[]`, а именно по его имени) эквивалентно обращению к  указателю на начало массива. Поэтому `A + i` – это адресная арифметика.

Comment: Прошу прощения за некропостинг
То ли идет ЗАПИСЬ в адрес, то ли булево сравнение значений.
42 никогда не изменится, а *42 - легко